# VSCode - How to manage User Secrets in .Net Core 2.0+ API

Tags: macos, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm very familiar with how to create and manage user secrets in Visual Studio by right clicking the project in the solution explorer.  And managing the

Is there a way to do this in VS Code?
Does it matter if it's on a Mac?
Is there an extension that will provide a similar experience?

Comment: The mechanism is provided by .NET Core itself, not Visual Studio. It's used the same no matter which IDE is used. Check [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows)

Answer (score 30):

Download extension i.e .NET Core User Secrets.Then right click on .csproj file of your project to get Manage user secrets file.